ASP.NET Core MVC web app : antiforgery tokens
I am wondering if anyone can help me. I am trying to get [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] action method to fire and it appears not be. I was trying to check if the anti forgery token logic was actually doing anything and it appears not to be, unless I have setup it up incorrectly or I am just missing something obvious.
Inside the form I comment out:
@Html.AntiForgeryToken() 

while I still leave this attribute on the controller in place:
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

I do not get any error, despite the fact there is no token (if there is no token it should fail and cause / throw an error) and the model state is valid (which seems to be normal for this case).
Please see basic example:
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");

    var app = builder.Build();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAntiforgery();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    app.Run();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult SubmitForm(FormModel form)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

<form asp-action="SubmitForm" asp-controller="Home" method="post">

  @*   @Html.AntiForgeryToken() *@
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

So to sum up I am trying to get the antiforgery token to work.
Additional information:
When I add it as property into the model I can see the token 
And when I look inside the header I can see the cookie

It appears that if it is there or not [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]does not fire or it is just doing nothing.

Is the token in your request header?

@GHDevOps
When I un-comment it, yes I can see it within the header with the key name of "Cookie" and when I add "__RequestVerificationToken" as property of type string into the model I can also see it. Its like "ValidateAntiForgeryToken" is doing nothing when token is there or not there

The reason it still works is because despite you commenting-out the  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() call, ASP.NET Core's <form> tag-helper will still render the <input type="hidden" name="__RequestVerificationToken"> by-default, even if you don't explicitly call @Html.AntiForgeryToken(). See here in the source:

Defaults to false if user provides an action="" attribute or if the method is GET; true otherwise.

c.f.:
public class FormTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    // ...

    /// <summary>Whether the antiforgery token should be generated.</summary>
    /// <value>Defaults to <c>false</c> if user provides an <c>action</c> attribute
    /// or if the <c>method</c> is <see cref="FormMethod.Get"/>; <c>true</c> otherwise.</value>
    [HtmlAttributeName(AntiforgeryAttributeName)]
    public bool? Antiforgery { get; set; }

    // ...

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {

        var antiforgeryDefault = true;

        // ...

        if (this.Antiforgery ?? antiforgeryDefault)
        {
            var antiforgeryTag = Generator.GenerateAntiforgery(ViewContext);
            if (antiforgeryTag != null)
            {
                output.PostContent.AppendHtml(antiforgeryTag);
            }
        }
    }
}

The call to @Html.AntiForgeryToken() won't render a duplicate input because internally it checks-to-see if the default <input type="hidden" /> will be rendered anyway:
    public virtual IHtmlContent GenerateAntiforgery(ViewContext viewContext)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(viewContext);

        var formContext = viewContext.FormContext;
        if (formContext.CanRenderAtEndOfForm)
        {
            // Inside a BeginForm/BeginRouteForm or a <form> tag helper. So, the antiforgery token might have
            // already been created and appended to the 'end form' content (the AntiForgeryToken HTML helper does
            // this) OR the <form> tag helper might have already generated an antiforgery token.
            if (formContext.HasAntiforgeryToken)
            {
                return HtmlString.Empty;
            }

